# jquery iphone ui and jqtouch , which is better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jqtouch

[jquery iphone ui](http://iphone.hohli.com/) and jqtouch

they are lib of iphone ,  i want to choose one to use,

which is better ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only used jQTouch, and have been happy about it. It's a fairly light-weight, yet powerful framework.

[Peepcode](https://peepcode.com/products/jqtouch) has a nice introductory video tutorial on jQTouch for just $9. If you're evaluating it, you may want to give it a go.

One thing that took me a while to figure out is the use of a tab bar with jQTouch, which isn't directly supported with the current stable release. If you're using tab bar, you should use a later version of jQTouch.

JQuery iPhone UI seems like a more heavy-weight framework. I suggest you to get the full version and play with the demo applications that come with it. That should give you a good idea about the smoothness of the animations. One thing I found is that, this framework may actually support more than just WebKit, whereas jQTouch is pretty much targeted at WebKit browsers.